# How do i get my code to print out the change? I used modulus yet it's only printing out the remainder

Tags: java, int, double

```
public class Change {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount due: ");//Variable = amount
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the amount recieved from Customer: ");
        Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int customer = keyboard2.nextInt();//variable = customer

        double change = customer - amount;
        System.out.println("You need to give to customer");

        double remainingAmount = (double) (change * 100);

        double numDollars = remainingAmount / 100;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;

        double numQuarters = remainingAmount / 25;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;

        double numDimes = remainingAmount / 10;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;

        double numNickels = remainingAmount / 5;
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5;

        double numPennies = remainingAmount;

        System.out.println("Dollars: " + numDollars);
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + numQuarters);
        System.out.println("Dimes: " + numDimes);
        System.out.println("Nickels: " + numNickels);
        System.out.println("Pennies: " + numPennies);

    }

}
```

When I try running the code, I only recieve back the remainder 
for example when i type in Amount needed as `247` and enter the customer number `315` I get `68` as the remainder in the first statement of "Dollars: "

Comment: *I used modulus yet it's only printing out the remainder* uhh, that's what modulus does...

Comment: yes i know, but I guess i didn't word that correctly, i'm trying to take the modulus and then break it down further down into the next one which is quarters. For example the in my example the amount given 247 needed. Then the amount recieved is 315. The remainder is 68 correct? How do I get it to skip that and go to quarters since dollars which is allocated to 100? and quarters is the next in the sequence; yet it only prints out the remainder from the first Variable. Sorry !

Comment: The logic in your code actually looks fine to me.  You determine the number of a given coin using division, and then you use the modulus to carry over the remainder to try to use smaller coins.  What about your output is unexpected?

Comment: Enter the amount due: 247
Enter the amount recieved from Customer: 315
You need to give to customer
Dollars: 68.0
Quarters: 0.0
Dimes: 0.0
Nickels: 0.0
Pennies: 0.0   @TimBiegeleisen  My output is 68 as the remainder in the first "Dollars: "

Comment: You used the remainder operator. There is no modulus operator in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are always only seeing a dollar amount, and no coins, is that you prompt the user to input dollar amounts.  Your code then multiplies this dollar amount by 100 to determine the number of cents.  Since the input is always multiples of dolars, there will never be any remainder after dividing by 100, and hence there will never be any coins.

If you want to see some coins, then allow the user to enter dollar amounts with fractional cents, as `double` type input, and then you will see the cents in this (no pun intended):

```
System.out.print("Enter the amount due: ");//Variable = amount
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double amount = keyboard.nextDouble();       // e.g. 311.00

System.out.print("Enter the amount recieved from Customer: ");
Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
double customer = keyboard2.nextDouble();   // e.g. 320.49

double change = customer - amount;          // 9.4900000

int remainingAmount = (int)(change * 100);  // 949

int numDollars = remainingAmount / 100;     // 9 (49 gets truncated)
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100;    // 49 remainder

int numQuarters = remainingAmount / 25;     // 1 (24 gets truncated)
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 25;     // 24 remainder

int numDimes = remainingAmount / 10;        // 2 (4 gets truncated)
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10;     // 4 remainder

int numNickels = remainingAmount / 5;       // 0
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5;      // 4 remainder

int numPennies = remainingAmount;           // 4 pennies left

System.out.println("Dollars: " + numDollars);
System.out.println("Quarters: " + numQuarters);
System.out.println("Dimes: " + numDimes);
System.out.println("Nickels: " + numNickels);
System.out.println("Pennies: " + numPennies);
```